# How To prevent Oracle Timezone conversion

Tags: oracle

I have a date column defined as follows:

```
AUXILIARY_DT DATE
```

The date is inserted using the following snippet:

```
TO_DATE(p_auxiliary_dt, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
```

The webservice that connects to this database is in a different timezone than the client which consumes the webservice.

I am now trying to retrieve the date without having oracle muck with the date/time.

I have tried simply selecting the date column:

```
Select auxiliary_dt from SomeTable where id=1234;
```

I have tried converting the date to a string and converting it to a date client side:

```
Select to_char(gs.auxiliary_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as auxiliary_dt from SomeTable where id=1234;
```

However in both cases the date comes back in the timezone of the webservice, not the client.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: That doesn't make sense-- a `date` does not have a time zone.  If the column is really a `date` and not a `timestamp with [local] time zone`, Oracle can't do any conversion.  Your `insert` statement references `p_auxillary_dt` which implies that it is a parameter to a stored procedure.  Is it possible that whatever is passing in the `date` to this procedure is passing in a time you don't expect (i.e. the time on the middle tier rather than the client)?

Comment: Hmmm, it's possible.  I just to a look and there is a conversion from a .NET datetime to a string.  Perhaps that is the culprit?

Comment: That would seem to make sense.